# Catch Genbank File parsing error in Biopython

Tags: python, biopython

I have used the BioPython Entrez module to download a list of genbank files along the lines of [this post](http://www.biostars.org/p/19206/). In subsequently parsing these files I come across an error because the genbank file I have downloaded from Entrez is part of a provisional RefSeq given to an organism whose genome is not complete([NZ_CM000913.1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NZ_CM000913.1)). When I attempt to read this file I get a record error and my script stops. I am trying to write a function that can avoid these records. The simplest way would be to filter the records by size but I am wondering how to do this more 'bio-pythonically' - test to see if a file contains a record and then exclude if it doesn't. The current ValueError message is raised but will stop the script.

```
#the error message is something like this    
from Bio import SeqIO
gbkfile = 'NZ_CM000913.1'
SeqIO.read(open(gbkfile), 'gb')

      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 605, in read
        raise ValueError("No records found in handle")
```

For my looping I could use something like this:

```
#filter by length
for gbk in gbklist:
    if len(open(gbk).readlines()) < 50:
        print 'short file: exclude'
    else:
        process_gbk(gbk)
```

but I am wondering if I can catch the error message from within BioPython:

```
#generate GBK-file exception    
for gbk in gbklist:
    try: 
        SeqIO.read(open(gbk),'gb')
        process_gbk(gbk)
    except BiopythonIO: 
        'this file is not a genbank file'
        pass
```

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to just catch the ValueError. That makes sense unless you anticipate there being other types of ValueErrors that should be handled differently. A more robust solution is to extend SeqIO and overwrite the (hopefully modular!) method where "No records found in handle" is raised such that it raises a subclasses error that you can watch for and catch downstream. Whether that is preferable to just checking file length depends on how modular the SeqIO read method is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion is almost there! Here's to finish it off + a few handy perks (read commenting)

```
errorList = []                               # to store your erroneous files for later handling ;)

#generate GBK-file exception 
for gbk in gbklist:
    try: 
        SeqIO.read(open(gbk),'gb')
        process_gbk(gbk)
    except ValueError:                       # handles your ValueError
        print(gbk+' is not a genbank file')  # lets you know the file causing the error "live"
        errorList.append(gbk)                # logs the name of erroneous files in "errorList"
        continue                             # skips straight to the next loop
```

Comment: @zach I have done quite some work with this type of data on MATLAB as well as Python, feel free to ask if you have similar questions :)

Answer (score 2):

I can open [NZ_CM000913.1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NZ_CM000913.1) just fine using Biopython, actually:

```
>>> from Bio import SeqIO
>>> fname = 'NZ_CM000913.1.gbk'
>>> recs = SeqIO.read(fname, 'genbank')
>>> recs
SeqRecord(seq=UnknownSeq(6760392, alphabet = IUPACAmbiguousDNA(), character = 'N'), id='NZ_CM000913.1', name='NZ_CM000913', description='Streptomyces clavuligerus ATCC 27064 chromosome, whole genome shotgun sequence.', dbxrefs=['Project:47867 BioProject:PRJNA47867'])
```

Are you sure you've downloaded the file correctly and not an empty file?

Also, I noticed that you're feeding `open('NZ_CM000913.1.gbk')` to `SeqIO.read`. It's better (and easier to read) to simply feed the filename (`SeqIO.read('NZ_CM000913.1.gbk', 'genbank')`) to prevent leaving file handles unclosed.